# XSLT - How to apply if-else or choose-when for the below xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I using the below xml,xslt where I want to check the condition as if  attribute nominee start with '1 2' means then just get the value of the nominee else concat the '1 2' with nominee value

XML

```
<catalog>
<cd nominee ="1 2 First">
    <title company="Grammy" price="10.20">1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
    <artist all="type">Many</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
</cd>
<cd nominee ="Second">
    <title company="Grammy" price="20.20">Grammy Nominees</title>
    <artist all="type">Many</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

XSLT

```
    <xsl:template match="catalog">
      <fo:block>
       <xsl:if test ="cd/@value">
        <xsl:if test="starts-with(., '1 2')">
                <xsl:value-of select="cd/@value" />
        </xsl:if>
       <xsl:if test="not(starts-with(.,'1 2'))">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat('1 2',cd/@value)" /> 
       </xsl:if> 
     </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Tried this too

```
<xsl:template match="catalog">
      <fo:block>
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test ="cd/@value">
          <xsl:if test="starts-with(., '1 2')">
                <xsl:value-of select="cd/@value" />
          </xsl:if>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="concat('1 2',cd/@value)" /> 
       </xsl:otherwise> 
     </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

By using the above XSLT I'm Always getting false and get output as `<fo:block>'1 2 1 2 First'</fo:block>`

Output that I want is

First cd element

```
<fo:block>'1 2 First'</fo:block>
```

Second cd element

```
<fo:block>'1 2 Second'</fo:block>
```

Thanks !!

Comment: You have a condition checking cd/@value, but the cd element does not have a 'value' attribute? And I am guessing instead of "starts-with(., '1 2')" you want "starts-with(cd/@nominee, '1 2')".

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn which XSLT instructions change the context, and which don't. Within a template rule with match="catalog", the context item is the `catalog` element, and it's not changed by `xsl:when` or `xsl:if`. So your test in the starts-with needs to select from the `catalog` element.

But it's a bit more subtle than this, because there is more than one `cd` (I assume you meant `cd/@nominee` rather than `cd/@value`, by the way).

The way to write this one is using template rules. What you really, want, I think, is something like:

```
<xsl:template match="catalog">
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd[starts-with(@nominee, '1 2')]">
   <xsl:value-of select="@nominee"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('1 2 ', @nominee)"/>
</xsl:template>
```